# Random number using React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I wrote this code, but when I run it, I only get a blank page. What is wrong?
It does seem that I am close to the answer. I've tried everything, but it is still not working.

```
class Button extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
   random: 0
    }
   }


   render() {
   var min = 1;
   var max = 100;
   var rand =  min + (Math.random() * (max-min));
   handleClick() {
    this.setState ({this.state.random + this.rand})
   }
    return (
      <div>
       <button value="Click me!" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)></button>
       </div>
      );

 React.render(<Button />, document.querySelector('#container'));

  }
}
```

JSFIDLLE: https://jsfiddle.net/1cban4oy/12/

Comment: There's no action binded to button.

Comment: Even with action binded, it did not work.

Comment: Your snippet is not valid JS. You've got your `handleClick` function inside `render` somehow, and `React.render` is inside the `Button`.

Comment: are you really trying to run JSX in the browser?  are you transpiling it?  what errors appear in your browser's console?

Comment: Help us reproduce your problem.  JSX usually requires some HTML loading the page, etc.  Please add everything you need to reproduce the issue to a well known javascript REPL (like jsbin) and give us the link to that.

Comment: @Dan O Yes, in the browser.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/q/1527803/104380 (see sidebar)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Remove all your logic from the render function and add it to the click handler method. Also the onClick is missing a curly bracket at the end. Finally you're not indicating the state property you're updating in the `setState()` method.

This basically seems to do what you're after:
https://codesandbox.io/s/98n9EkEOJ

This is the code just in case:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class Button extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state = { random: 0 };
  }

  handleClick() {
    const min = 1;
    const max = 100;
    const rand = min + Math.random() * (max - min);
    this.setState({ random: this.state.random + rand });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Click</button>
        <div>The number is: {this.state.random}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<Button />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 9):

- Firstly, you didn't set the state properly.
- Secondly, use arrow functions so you can avoid problematic binding.
- Thirdly, you didn't display the `random` value anywhere.
- Lastly - you can move the `min` and `max` variables outside the `render` function. Also the whole math logic responsible for rolling a random number can be moved into the `handleClick` function.

Working code:

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      random: null,
    }
  }

  min = 1;
  max = 100;

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({random: this.min + (Math.random() * (this.max - this.min))});
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me</button>
        {this.state.random}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I like the tip on using arrow functions -- thanks!  I normally solve that using `this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);` in the constructor.  The arrow method is much cleaner!

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
class Button extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            random: null
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    handleClick() {
        const min = 1;
        const max = 100;
        const random = min + (Math.random() * (max - min));
        this.setState({ random })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button value="Click me!" onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.state.random}</button>
            </div>
        );


    }
}
React.render(<Button />, document.querySelector('#container'));
```

Answer (score 3):

i think you need move this line

```
React.render(<Button />, document.querySelector('#container'));
```

not only from `render` method but even from the class.

and you need to do some changes

so your code be like :

```
class Button extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
   random: 0
    }
   }

   handleClick = () => {
      var min = 1;
      var max = 100;
      var rand =  min + (Math.random() * (max-min));
      this.setState ({this.state.random : rand})
   }

   render() {


    return (
      <div>
       <button value="Click me!" onClick={this.handleClick}> {this.state.random} </button>
       </div>
      );
  }


} 

React.render(<Button />, document.querySelector('#container'));
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an easy way to create Random Number using

> random-string

```
var x = randomString({
length: 8,
numeric: true,
letters: false,
special: false,

});
```

Here is the documentation for more details 
[random-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/random-string)

Answer (score 0):

**Random number in an Array in React:**
[Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)]

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);

  function randomNumberInRange(min, max) {
    //  get number between min and max
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }

  const handleClick = () => {
    setNum(randomNumberInRange(1, 5));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>number is: {num}</h2>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Generate random number</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```