# Why React variable render again in JSX?

Tags: reactjs, variables, jsx, render

```js
function App() {
    const puzzles = [...Array(12)].map((_, i) => i).sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
    console.log(puzzles)
    return (
         <Game puzzles={puzzles} />
    );
}

const Game = (props) => {
    return <div>{props.puzzles}</div>;
};
```

I set a const rand array [puzzles] from 0 to 2 at App.js

then I pass the [puzzles] variable to the Game Component,

I console.log the [puzzles] at App.js and Game Component,

somehow the results are different.....

```
[1,2,0] log in App.js

[0,2,1] log in Component
```

It seen like the array is running again somewhere inside the JSX,

Can someone tell me if I missed anything? Many thanks!!!

Comment: I think you'll need to provide your actual component code for folks to help

Comment: Your code looks good and works fine here, https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hawtpd?file=src/App.js

Comment: is there any other code that you haven't shared?

Comment: @SanishJoseph it fails in Strict mode since the render phase should be pure (idempotent, no side-effects, etc)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random number using React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45175836/random-number-using-react-js)

Comment: @EmileBergeron After I change the to Fragment mode, the problem had gone!
If I want to keep using Strict mode, where do I need to modify my code?

Comment: Yes, you should change your code to something similar to the question I linked, or just using state would help. Render should be pure, as soon as the app re-renders, a new puzzle will be generated and it becomes unpredictable.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Ok I try to change it to state, many thanks!

Comment: @EmileBergeron good to know that things behave differently in strict mode.

Comment: @SanishJoseph Strict mode is a safe guard against these types of bugs, it runs the render cycle twice with the same input and it highlights situation where the rendering isn't pure, like in this question. Strict mode should behave identically, except when there's a potential bug in the components code.

Comment: Interesting. I am using `<React.StrictMode>` in my projects and I never knew it had such a logic behind. Yes I used to get warnings especially from MUI 4. Thank yo for explaining.